# java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: "an error...near '?,?,?,?,?,?)' "

Tags: java, mysql

I do not know why I get this error. What is wrong with the path of (?,?,?,?,?,?)?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?,?,?,?,?,?)' at line 1
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdateInternal(StatementImpl.java:1355)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeLargeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:2128)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1264)
at com.theanh.dao.StudentMySQLDAO.createStudent(StudentMySQLDAO.java:46)
at com.theanh.dao.StudentMySQLDAO.main(StudentMySQLDAO.java:26)
```

I have looked at the right syntax on [Javatpoint](https://www.javatpoint.com/PreparedStatement-interface):

> String sql="insert into emp values(?,?,?)";

My syntax is:

> String createSQL = "insert into student values(?,?,?,?,?,?)";

Based on my database script:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `student`;
CREATE TABLE `student`
(
    `id`       int(40)      NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name`     varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `birthday` DATE         NOT NULL,
    `sex`      bool         NOT NULL, # zero is considered as false, and non-zero value is considered as true.
    `gpa`      float,
    `rank`     varchar(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB
  AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
  DEFAULT CHARSET = latin1;
```

Now, I can not spot any error in my syntax. I know we can use String only to build SQL query, but i want to use `PreparedStatement` class. The connection to database is fine

Any suggestion?

Below is details:
Here is mysql jdbc version:

> ```
>  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>mysql</groupId>
>         <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
>         <version>8.0.16</version>
>     </dependency>
> ```

My class where it runs and throws Exception:

```
public class StudentMySQLDAO implements StudentDAO {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            new StudentMySQLDAO().createStudent(new Student(300, "Steven",
                    LocalDate.of(1995, 10, 20), true, 9.0f, "VERY GOOD"));
        }
    
        public void createStudent(Student student) throws Exception {
            // Codes to do real operations in MySQL database, assuming that student existent has been checked in db
            // Create SQL to add the student to database
            String createSQL = "insert into student values(?,?,?,?,?,?)";
            // Open a connection
            Connection conn = new DBContext().getConnection();
            conn.setAutoCommit(false);
            // Execute a query
            PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(createSQL);
            ps.setInt(1, student.getId());
            ps.setString(2, student.getName());
            ps.setString(3, student.getBirthday().format(formatter));
            ps.setInt(4, student.getSex() ? 1 : 0);
            ps.setFloat(5, student.getGpa());
            ps.setString(6, student.getRank());
            ps.executeUpdate(createSQL);
            conn.rollback();
            // Close all
            conn.close();
            ps.close();
        }
}
```

The basic, nothing fancy Student.class:

```
public class Student {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private LocalDate birthday;
    private boolean sex; // True = male, False = female
    private float gpa;
    private String rank; // Only has values "Very good", "Good", "Average"

    public Student() {
    }

    public Student(int id, String name, LocalDate birthday, boolean sex, float gpa, String rank) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.birthday = birthday;
        this.sex = sex;
        this.gpa = gpa;
        this.rank = rank;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public LocalDate getBirthday() {
        return birthday;
    }

    public void setBirthday(LocalDate birthday) {
        this.birthday = birthday;
    }

    public boolean getSex() {
        return sex;
    }

    public void setSex(boolean sex) {
        this.sex = sex;
    }

    public Float getGpa() {
        return gpa;
    }

    public void setGpa(Float gpa) {
        this.gpa = gpa;
    }

    public String getRank() {
        return rank;
    }

    public void setRank(String rank) {
        this.rank = rank;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Student student = (Student) o;
        return id == student.id &&
                sex == student.sex &&
                Float.compare(student.gpa, gpa) == 0 &&
                name.equals(student.name) &&
                birthday.equals(student.birthday) &&
                rank.equals(student.rank);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id, name, birthday, sex, gpa, rank);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", birthday=" + birthday +
                ", sex=" + sex +
                ", gpa=" + gpa +
                ", rank='" + rank + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

My MySQL workbench version: `8.0.16`

Comment: your id is auto increment, you're not supposed to enter it by your code. Also, javatpoint isn't exactly the most reliable source to learn from.

Comment: ok let's me check. Can you suggest a source?

Comment: You can  try removing the id column from the insert statement

Comment: Don't pass the query string to `executeUpdate`

Comment: Stultuske I think the auto increment is not the problem. I build query in String and then add student with new id, it is ok. Stultuske,Mohsin Khan, Nick, can you help me rewrite the query using PreparedStatement? I am trying but it is just not work.

Comment: @VuAnh did you try what I suggested?

Comment: What i should pass it into @Nick? I dont have the clue.

Comment: @VuAnh nothing. Just `ps.executeUpdate();`

Comment: I see that you removed the column names from the insert statement although it is always a  good practice to include them except the auto increment column. Also `rank` is a reserved word in MySql since version 8.0.2 and should be enclosed in backticks.

Comment: @Nick, I have try it. The error is not showing anymore, but the data is not being inserted to the database.

Comment: @VuAnh that may be because of the `rank` and/or `id` issues...

Comment: I think not, i have rewritten the query to: "insert into student (name, birthday, sex, gpa) values(?,?,?,?)"; to avoid id and rank, but it still give me the same error. I have aslo change the line:                                                      
  ps.setString(1, student.getName());       ps.setString(2, student.getBirthday().format(formatter));
        ps.setInt(3, student.getSex() ? 1 : 0);
        ps.setFloat(4, student.getGpa());

Comment: Again something is wrong I guess you are trying to put 1:0 as int in Sex column which is Boolean can you try putting  true or false instead

Comment: you don't need `conn.rollback()` since you are nothing working on transaction queries, its only one insert statement, `ps.executeUpdate()` will return the number of updated record and in your case, it would be only one so you can say if `ps.executeUpdate() == 1` other ways rollback, also it would be better to make select statement to check whether student exists or not if exists update else insert your query

Comment: also will not update any record since you are making the `conn.setAutoCommit(false);`, you can remove it or at the end add `conn.commit();`

Comment: Yea, I have solved my problems guys. First, do not pass anything to executeUpdate, just ps.executeUpdate();. And then it is just matter of commit and rollback, sorry for my mistakes. @Nick, you are right at the beginning, thanks you.

Comment: If you have solved your problem, you should either accept the answer that helped you solve the problem, or post your answer. Please do not add solutions to the question itself, nor add things like "SOLVED" to the title of your question. I have rolled back your last edits to the state when your question was still a question.

Comment: @VuAnh I'm glad you've got it working. It was a real team effort

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't using the `PreparedStatement`'s `executeUpdate` method to execute the statement with placeholders, but the `executeUpdate(String)` method inherited from the base `Statement`. Once the statement is prepared, you just need to call `ps.executeUpdate()`, without an argument.

As a side note, you're calling `rollback()` after you perform the insertion, meaning nothing will be committed to the database.